# playbooks and roles organization

Tags: ansible

How would you organize this example into playbooks and nodes? I have trouble understanding exactly how to divide playbooks and roles going by best practices

production:

```
check status of web server production a
check status of web server production b
check status of web server production c

enable web server production a
enable web server production b
enable web server production c
```

test:

```
check status of web server test a
check status of web server test b
check status of web server test c

enable web server test a
enable web server test b
enable web server test c
```

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. I asked to close. Moreover, it's [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Ansible best practices for directory layout https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout

A **role** is set of tasks that can be reused and a **playbook** is where we can define the mapping between roles and hosts (inventories).

I can see in your question that there are common tasks for different hosts.
A possible organization could be the alternative layout suggested in the official docs https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout:

```
inventories/
    production/
              hosts #Here you define the servers for prod
    test/
        hosts #Here you define the servers for test
main.yml # A playbook where you define which roles you want to execute and the hosts.  
roles/
      common/
            main.yml
      checkservers/
            main.yml
      anotherole/
            main.yml
```